# Discord py cryptocurrency API command not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command that is supposed to get the price of a given cryptocurrency but it's not working. Heres the code:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def crypto(self, ctx, cc = None):
        try:
            if cc is None:
                ccbed=discord.Embed(title='Command Usage:', description=f'/crypto [crypto currency]', colour=random.randint(0x000000, 0xffffff), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
                await ctx.send(embed=ccbed)

            else:
                url = f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={cc}&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur%2Cgbp"
                stats = requests.get(url)
                json_stats = stats.json()
                usdprice = json_stats["usd"]
                europrice = json_stats["eur"]
                gbpprice = json_stats["gbp"]

                ccbed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"**Current price of {cc}**", description="This data might be inaccurate.", colour=random.randint(0x000000, 0xffffff), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
                ccbed2.add_field(name="**USD:**", value=usdprice, inline=True)
                ccbed2.add_field(name="**EURO:**", value=europrice, inline=True)
                ccbed2.add_field(name="**GBP:**", value=gbpprice, inline=True)

                await ctx.send(embed=ccbed2)

        except:
            ccbed3 = discord.Embed(title="Invalid crypto currency or API error.", colour=random.randint(0x000000, 0xffffff), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
            ccbed3.set_author(name="Error!")
            await ctx.send(embed=ccbed3)
```

When I run the command it triggers the Invalid cryptocurrency or API error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur%2Cgbp"
>>> import requests
>>> stats = requests.get(url)
>>> json_stats = stats.json()
>>> json_stats
{'bitcoin': {'usd': 39125, 'eur': 32474, 'gbp': 28473}}
>>> usdprice = json_stats["usd"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'usd'
>>> usdprice = json_stats["bitcoin"]["usd"]
>>>
```

Execute your code, line by line then you will see the error.
`usdprice = json_stats["usd"]` will always return an error. Do something like `usdprice = json_stats[cc]["usd"]` or better iterate over it in case you specified multiple currencies:
`for k, v in json_stats.items():`

Don't write a general try except block (`except KeyError:`). Specify the error you expect in the except. Also when posting a debugging question you should supply the error traceback.

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur%2Cgbp returns some result but
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=btc&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur%2Cgbp results an empty dictionary.

Both will lead to an error in your current code but they are of different origin.